# MS Access Database - Chart Drawing From Lookup Control

Tags: ms-access, graph, charts

I am trying to create a pie chart in a MS Access report.  The problem is that the field in the table from which I am trying to draw the data is a lookup field, drawing its data from another table.  So when the pie chart is rendered, the labels are coming up as the numerical id for the entries rather than the text labels.

The structure is something like this:

Discrepancies Table:
column1 - ID
column2 - Name
column3 - Category - lookup from categories table

Categories Table:
ID
category (name of the category)

In the discrepancies form I have the category field bound to the "category" column (column1), so the text label appears in the table.

However, in the pie chart, which draws from the category field in the Discrepancies table, the label is the numeric ID of the category rather than the name.

How can I get the name to appear as the label rather than the ID?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by creating and basing my pie chart on a query, rather than by pointing it a row source.

The query was SELECT DISTINCTROW categories.category, Count(*) AS [Count Of discrepancies]
FROM categories INNER JOIN discrepancies ON categories.[ID] = discrepancies.[category]
GROUP BY categories.category;